# How to have a fixed element scroll along with parent element in popup dialog?

Tags: css, dialog, position, overflow

I'll try to be as clear as possible.

I have a `dialog` that popups on the page, the dialog might have a lot of info that it has to be scrollable. In the dialog I have custom dropdowns such as a datepicker that need to pop out of the dialog, similar to what `select` does when clicked.

If I set `position:absolute` it opens up but inside the dialog. Which is not what we need. If I try `position:fixed` then at first glance it looks great, but when I scroll, it disconnects from its parent.

I read tens of articles and SO answers, as well as looked over many codepens. Though I could not find a single working example.

Here is the codepen I built: https://codepen.io/yisman/pen/VwgLxEv

I would appreciate any help.

TIA

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin:0px
}
#mainbody {
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

#maincontenet {
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: blue;
  flex-grow:1 /*not critical*/
}
#popout{
  background-color: yellow; 
  /*position:absolute;*/
  position:fixed;
}
#innerwrap{
  position:relative;
 }
#dialog{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  max-width:30vw;
   max-height:20vh;
  overflow-y:auto;
  
}
```

```html
<dialog open id="dialog">
      <input value="washington"/>
   <div id="innerwrap">
     <input value="george"/>
    <div id="popout">
      read more and more<br/> 
      and more and more and more<br/> 
       and more and more and more<br/> 
       and more and more and more<br/> 
     </div>
   </div>
     <input value="president"/>
    <input value="president"/>
   <input value="president"/>
   <input value="president"/>
     <input value="president"/>
   <input value="president"/>
   <input value="president"/>
    <input value="president"/>
   <input value="president"/>
   <input value="president"/>
    <input value="president"/>
   <input value="president"/>
   <input value="president"/>
    </dialog>
<div id="mainbody">
  
  HEADER
  <div id="maincontenet">
   
    A<br />
    B<br />
    C<br />
    D<br />
    E<br />
    F<br />    
    G<br />
    H<br />
    I<br />
    J<br />
    K<br />
    L<br />
  </div>
  FOOTER
</div>
```

Comment: I think `position: absolute` is the right choice. What is it about the behaviour of `position: absolute` that you do not like?

Comment: hi. thanks for all the work and the editing. I changed the codepen to `absolute`. If you will run it now you will see the yellow popup is expanded "inside" the dialog, making it basically non-visible by the user. I need it opened on top of the dialog, even if has to exit the border of the dialog. I added a `select` in the codepen. When you open the select, you can see how I would like it to popout. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, so I guess you need `position: fixed` then, but when the popup is displayed you could try setting `pointer-events: none` on the dialog to prevent it from scrolling.

Comment: Thanks, but I do need the option of scrolling. So that would not be a good idea. Any other ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: You don’t want it to scroll while the popup is displayed, though. So when you show the popup, set `pointer-events: none` on the dialog, then when you hide the popup, set `pointer-events: initial` on the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Breaking out of a parent container with `overflow: hidden/auto/scroll` while preserving correct positioning isn't trivial, without resorting to JS. You have a couple of other options:

Use a `<select>` or `<input type="date">` for your date picker. These will always be layered correctly with respect to `<dialog>`s and other top-layer elements. Also, these native controls give a much better user experience on mobile and tablets.

Or, if you absolutely must use a non-native select/input solution, consider converting your dialog to become an own page in your app. When a dialog becomes so long that needs scrolling, that's usually an indication that it's too long.

Alternatively, if possible, make sure your dialog doesn't contain too much content, so it can safely have `overflow: visible`. That way you have no overflow constraints, but that isn't a guarantee you won't get into trouble on smaller viewports.

Comment: Hi. I appreciate your answer. I cannot use the built in elements as they don't give the functionality that I need.  The scrolling is a must, but I don't mind as a last resort to try JS. Can you provide an implementation? Please remember that I'm in `React`.